# Error System.TypeLoadException

Tags: android, xamarin

Al ejecutar mi MainActivity me marca este error:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Android.Gms.Common.Apis.GoogleApiClient/IConnectionCallbacksInvoker' from assembly 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

he intentado desinstalando y volviendo a instalar el Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base pero no me ayuda.

Aquí el MainActivity:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace App
{
[Activity(Label = "Befy", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    }
}
}
```

Alguna idea que me pueda ayudar?, no sé si le hará falta alguna referencia o algo, gracias!

Comment: Que android version estas usando?